How to get desired package structure with setuptools?
I'm trying to create a package using setuptools on a project with a custom file structure. This is the structure:
├── pyproject.toml
├── scripts
│   ├── layers
│   │   ├── mypackage
|   |   |   ├──module1
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py

And I would like to have a distributed file structure like this:
├──mypackage
|   ├──module1

But instead it's like this when I run sdist:
├── pyproject.toml
├── scripts
│   └── layers
│       ├── mypackage
│       │   ├── module1
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py

This is my setup.cfg:
[options]
package_dir =
    = scripts/layers
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
where = scripts/layers

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

The sdist keeps the original structure. You need to look inside a wheel if you want to see the structure as it will be installed, or actually install it.
